# How can I place the 3 dots in the last word of the 3rd line of a mutli-line text in CSS

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am having the following css code:

```
.description-text {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        line-height: 1.375em;
        max-height: 4.125em;
        /* margin-right: -1em;
        padding-right: 1em; */
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        color: #7a7a7a;

        &:before {
          content: '...';
          position: absolute;
          right: 4.125em;
          bottom: 0;
        }

        &:after {
          content: '...';
          position: absolute;
          //right: 0;
          height: 3rem;
          margin-top: 0.2rem;
        }
```

My html element:

```
<p class="description-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
```

I am trying to show only the 3 lines of the above text and add at the end of the last character 3 dots. I achieved this. My problem is that I want to put the 3 dots exactly at the end of the text.

Any suggestions? I do not want to do it by justifying the text align. I want a solution that works for any kind of text that the user may put inside the `<p>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with this CSS.You can see the effect by reducing the size of browser window.

https://codepen.io/Rishab2019/pen/bGVRxLO

```
  .description-text {

    position: relative;
    line-height: 1.375em;
    max-height: 4.125em;
    /* margin-right: -1em;
    padding-right: 1em; */
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #7a7a7a;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;


   }

    &:before {
      content: '...';
      position: absolute;
      right: 4.125em;
      bottom: 0;
    }

    &:after {
      content: '...';
      position: absolute;
      //right: 0;
      height: 3rem;
      margin-top: 0.2rem;
    }
```